# In a given string, match all numbers where a certain word is not present either ahead or behind it [Regex, Python]

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

> "10.0 banana 30 apple 50 TOM 70 mango 100 peach 33 TOM 4.5"

and from this, I want to match only numbers which do not have the word `TOM` either behind or ahead of them.

So match should be only numbers `10.0`, `30`, `100`; numbers `50`, `70`, `33` and `4.5` should not be matched.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eh1lOt/2). I have tried with negative lookbehinds and negative lookaheads, but I am missing something, it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookaround patterns like this:

```
(?<!\bTOM )(?<![\d.])\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?![\d.])(?! TOM\b)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/v8IaEu/1